# Stem and leaf plot algorithm

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement a stem and plot algorithm in MATLAB for educational purposes. Before I post my code, let me introduce what the steps of my  approach are. Let us consider that we have  two digit numbers:

```
A=[20 12 13 21 56 13  16 17 22 23 24];
```

Stems can be given by

```
stems=fix(A/10)
stems =
     2     1     1     2     5     1     1     1     2     2     2
```

and leafs can be  given by

```
leaf=fix(mod(A,10))

leaf =

     0     2     3     1     6     3     6     7     2     3     4
```

What I have done, is to sort the stems and according to that sort leafs as well:

```
[stems, index]=sort(stems,'ascend')
leaf=leaf(index)
stems =
     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     5
leaf =
     2     3     3     6     7     0     1     2     3     4     6
```

This is the basic idea:

- 1. Count the frequency of occurrence of each number in `stems`
- 2. Take that many elements from `leaf`

Repeat this procedure for each stem, where at each step I am shortening the `leaf` array. So for instance for `stems = 1`,  we have `[5 1]`, so I will have

```
leaf(1:5)
ans =
     2     3     3     6     7
leaf(1:5)=[]
leaf =
     0     1     2     3     4     6
```

`stems = 2` is again 5 times,  so again:

```
leaf(1:5)
ans =
     0     1     2     3     4
leaf(1:5)=[]
leaf =
     6
```

Now for `stems = 5`, we have  1 leaf

```
leaf(1)
ans =
     6
```

For this I used a map container and I have created the following code:

```
function stem_leaf_plot(v)
if ~isnumeric(v)  %  check that  program will accept  array as a  integers
    error( 'Input V must be numeric'); 

end
stems=fix(v/10);
leaf=fix(rem(v,10));
[stems, index]=sort(stems,'ascend');
leaf=leaf(index);
string_stems=num2str(stems);
%%  count  occurence of each stem
MAP=containers.Map();
n=length(stems); % total element of  stems array
for  ii=1:n
    if isKey(MAP,string_stems(ii))
        MAP(string_stems(ii))= MAP(string_stems(ii))+1;
        else
         MAP(string_stems(ii))=1;
    end
end
MAP_count=length(MAP);

stem=num2str(cell2mat(keys(MAP)));
for jj=1:MAP_count
    frequency=(MAP(string_stems(jj)));
    fprintf('leafs of stem %d',stem(jj));
    disp(leaf(1:frequency));
    leaf(1:frequency)=[]; % delete   elements  step by step
end

end
```

However, the result of my code is

```
stem_leaf_plot(A)
leafs of stem 32     2     3     3     6
leafs of stem 49     7     0     1     2     3     4     6
```

What is wrong?

Comment: i think i realized problem

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with containers, and not with arrays, like in your example? That seems clear enough, whereas you don't explain why you want to use containers.

Comment: containers for frequency counting

Comment: That doesn't explain me why you are using containers instead of arrays. I can count perfectly well in arrays.

Comment: ok let me  think about it

Comment: [a,b]=hist(x,unique(x));  using this code

Comment: thank  youuuuuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 0):

After suggestion of [@Adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41967064/stem-and-leaf-plot-algorithm#comment71113694_41967064) I used `hist` to count frequencies, instead of a container. Here is my updated code:

```
function stem_leaf_plot(v)
if ~isnumeric(v)  %  check that  program will accept  array as a  integers
    error( 'Input V must be numeric'); 

end
stems=fix(v/10);
leaf=fix(rem(v,10));
[stems, index]=sort(stems,'ascend');
leaf=leaf(index);
[a,b]=hist(stems,unique(stems));
n=length(a);
for ii=1:n
    fprintf('leaf of  stem  %d is ',b(ii));
    leaf(1:a(ii))
    leaf(1:a(ii))=[];

end


       >> A=[20 12 13 21 56 13  16 17 22 23 24];
>> stem_leaf_plot(A)
leaf of  stem  1 is 
ans =

     2     3     3     6     7

leaf of  stem  2 is 
ans =

     0     1     2     3     4

leaf of  stem  5 is 
ans =

     6
```

Comment: can i  make output  a bit more beautiful?

Comment: I wouldn't dump output to the console at all, rather save it to cells. If you want this for educational purpose, you should put another `fprintf` statement with `leaf(1:a(ii))` to get rid of the `ans =`. Additionally I can recommend `format compact` at the beginning of your code, to get rid of the white lines in between your console output.